# Trying to calculate the indirect effects in a multilevel structural equation model using Stata. Can someone confirm than I have this code right?

Tags: stata, mlm, structural-equation-model

I'm trying to build a multilevel structural equation model in stata, using Example 42g  in the Stata handbook as a guide. My code is working, but I'm going off-book a little in calculating the indirect effects and could just use a sanity check from a pro.

I'm testing a moderated mediation model in which

```
Path A = fear <- i.theme + i.condition + i.theme#i.condition + easyseec
Path B = ppt_ave <- fear
Path C' = ppt_ave <- i.theme + i.condition + i.theme#i.condition + easyseec
```

The model uses nested data -- easyseec is nested under subjects, so I've added a random intercept and random slope under the variable responseid.

The .gsem output roughly tracks with the output the same model built in R with lmer, so I feel good about that. But I could really use an eyeball on the .nlcom below. This should calculate the indirect effect for a particular theme/condition contrast, right?

```
    . gsem (ppt_ave <- fear i.theme i.condition i.theme#i.condition easyseec M1[responseid]) (fear <- i.theme i.condition i.theme#i.condition easyseec M2[responseid])

    . nlcom _b[ppt_ave:fear]*(_b[fear:2.theme]+_b[fear:2.condition]+_b[fear:2.theme#2.condition]+_b[fear:easysee])
```

Comment: You may be better off asking this on Statalist. I don't think a lot of people with knowledge about sem hang out on SO.